# Error npm run server - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, servidor, npm

Estoy corriendo el comando npm run server, pero obtengo el siguiente error. ¿Cómo hago para solucionarlo? 
Aparece un listado largo de errores, los cuales necesito saber su solución. A continuación el código.
Muchas gracias.

```
C:\Users\Giova\Documents\Job\RefactorSocialskin\socialskin-fe>npm run server

> socialskin@0.0.0 server C:\Users\Giova\Documents\Job\RefactorSocialskin\socialskin-fe
> node local.js

C:\Users\Giova\Documents\Job\RefactorSocialskin\socialskin-fe\node_modules\angular-persistence\index.js:4
export { PersistenceService, AbstractCachedService, StorageType, PersistenceModule } from './src/angular-persistence';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.ukPL (C:\Users\Giova\Documents\Job\RefactorSocialskin\socialskin-fe\dist\server\main.js:10330:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Giova\Documents\Job\RefactorSocialskin\socialskin-fe\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
    at Object.VHQ1 (C:\Users\Giova\Documents\Job\RefactorSocialskin\socialskin-fe\dist\server\main.js:6546:31)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! socialskin@0.0.0 server: `node local.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the socialskin@0.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Giova\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-01T19_15_45_228Z-debug.log
```

Adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Angular se corre con `ng serve -o`. Lo que estas queriendo correr es un fichero de `node`, que no son lo mismo.

Comment: tal como comenta @Legna estas corriendo un fichero `node` con [ESM(JS módulos)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/M%C3%B3dulos) y actualmente en node no soporta esta sintaxis por defecto. Aquí tienes una pequeña guia de como activar dicha sintaxis. https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-enable-es-modules-nodejs/. Usa el `require` para importar archivos que es lo que esta soportado por defecto

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienen razón..